# Using an external flash drive with a Snappy application

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I'm developing an application that utilizes the Raspberry Pi 2 and will most likely use Snappy.  Many of the systems will be standalone (not normally connected to the Internet).  I need to manage the software configuration prior to sale and upgrade the software when the Pi is connected to the Internet.

From what I've read so far, it looks like Snapcraft is an appropriate tool, but I have many, many questions.  Let me start with just one.

The Pi has a permanently attached USB Flash Drive that I need to mount at startup.  My understanding is that I can do that in `/etc/fstab`.  Is that compatible with Snappy and Snapcraft?  Am I even asking the right question?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: snapcraft is only relevant for building snaps. Maybe split your questions?

Answer (score 4):

That's a good question to start with! I don't think we've defined a formal way for a device to mount a disk. The general zen of Ubuntu Core / snappy would say that we want to offer that disk to a single snap (application) on the device.

If your device is really only going to do one thing, then that will be easy from a security point of view. If you are going to want to have a general device with all sorts of snaps from the store, then we'll also need to think about the security implications of mounting disks, because (believe it or not) mounting disks is not something that can easily be done securely; you prety much need to trust that the disk filesystem hasn't been designed to mess with your kernel.

We'd probably be comfortable with this in  general purpose device (with other snaps from the store) if it was an ext4 disk.

I would suggest you bounce this question to the snappy-devel list, it's a very good one.

Comment: s/prety/pretty/